# using spring 3 latest source in apache tomcat 6.0.14

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, spring-security

Is latest spring 3 framework compatible with apache tomcat application server - version 6.0.14?

Also can what is the best version of hibernate i can use along with latest version of spring.

Is it fine to use configuration xml file in the spring 3 application setup instead of @configuration annotation in the code ?

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: answer selected ! done !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - Spring 3 will work fine with version 6.0.14 of Tomcat.

hibernate 4.1.7 should work fine.  Yes you can use an XML configuration rather than annotations, I've used both in Spring an Tomcat an it works fine.

To be honest, I find I prefer the annotations simply by the fact the XML tends to erode quite quickly and isn't touched for months after initial creation.

Comment: agreed ! I have a doubt - currently we have a spring version 2 based webapp . Can spring2 and spring3 webapps co exist together in a tomcat 6.0.14 version ?

Comment: To be honest the Spring concept only exists within each webapps folder - unless you are putting anything extra in server.xml or something like that "in theory" it should be fine, but I've never tested it myself.

Answer (score 0):

*spring 3 framework compatible with apache tomcat 6*
**yes.**

*best version of hibernate* 
**4, the latest and greatest.**

*Is it fine to use configuration xml file*
**yes**

(tomcat is not a full blown application server btw, that would be jboss glassfish et al)